# Poco parse XML document from byte buffer

Tags: c++, xml, poco

I need to convert `char buffer[]` to the Poco XML document. I tried to work through the Poco XML and Net tutorial but I could not see any example for this. Can anyone give a working example of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the string in a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), put that in a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). Now you should be able to use the input stream in POCO.